# If Array_Agg Struct have duplicate data how we can delete it in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

If Array_Agg Struct have duplicate data how we can delete it in Big Query Eg. (1 ,[1,2,3] )`` (2, [3,4,5]) (1, [1,2,3])

Required Output` (1 ,[1,2,3] ), (2, [3,4,5]),

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicates in your array of structs, you can unnest your arrays to flatten the data and then select distinct values. When duplicates are removed, recreate the arrays and structs. See approach below:

```sql
with sample_data as (
  select struct(1 as col1,[1,2,3] as col2) as test
  union all select struct(2 as col1 ,[3,4,5] as col2) as test
  union all select struct(1 as col1,[1,2,3] as col2) as test
),
t1 as (
select array_agg(test) as arr_of_structs from sample_data
),
-- disregard query above since it is for generating the sample data

remove_dups as (
select 
  distinct d_1.col1, d_2 
from t1, 
  unnest(arr_of_structs) as d_1,
  unnest(d_1.col2) as d_2
),
rebuild_struct as (
select 
  struct(col1,array_agg(d_2) as col2) as test 
from remove_dups
  group by col1
)

select array_agg(test) as arr_of_structs from rebuild_struct
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may consider this:

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT [STRUCT(1 AS int_field, [1,2,3] AS arr_field), (2, [3,4,5]), (1, [1,2,3])] array_agg_col
)
SELECT ARRAY(
         SELECT AS STRUCT * 
           FROM t.array_agg_col t1
        QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TO_JSON_STRING(t1)) = 1
       ) deduped_col
  FROM sample_table t;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

one more option:

```
with your_table as (
  select ([struct(1 as id ,[1,2,3] as arr), (2, [3,4,5]), (1, [1,2,3])]) array_agg_col
)
select array(
  select any_value(x)
  from t.array_agg_col x
  group by format('%t', x)
) new_col
from your_table t
```

with output

[image]

Comment: could you please help on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73912907/access-token-expired-while-iterating-table-result